# Unable to get a clean 'npm audit fix' on the SimpleAngularApp from course content. (Udemy Course Angular 10)

Tags: angular, npm, intellij-idea

My Development Environment

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA v. 2022.3.1, build #IU-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022
Java Version: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
NodeJS Version: 18.16.0
Angular CLI: 16.0.2
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: win32 x64 (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter - Azure VM)

I am not able to get a clean 'npm audit fix' or 'npm audit fix --force'. The below image shows results for 'npm audit fix'.

[IntelliJ Terminal Window - 'npm audit fix' command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BML4.png)

Can anyone provide me hints on how to handle the errors?

I ran -npm audit fix

Comment: Please don’t share error messages and logs as screenshot. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the top level dependencies / devDependencies in the package.json file had lots of deprecated dependencies. I built a new Angular program using a terminal window and typing 'ng new hello-world', which created a package.json file with no deprecated dependencies. I replaced the 'dependencies' and 'devDependencies' of the original project.json file with 'dependencies' and 'devDependencies' of the newly created package.json.

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it allowed me to run 'ng serve' and successfully render the Angular project in a browser.